# PDF Viewer in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, applet, html5-canvas, pdf-generation, pdfviewer

Presently in our web-application we used Java Applet as a PDF viewer, which also:

- blocks the user from saving the PDF document
- prints the PDF content to a *physical* printer (not to a soft printer i.e., save).

I recently heard that Google will end their Java Applet plugin support for Chrome.

Can I have the same limitations as mentioned above using a HTML5 based PDF viewer?

Comment: Chuckle, I think I ready your question exactly backwards!  Are you trying to **prevent saving** or **allow saving**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] blocks the user from saving the PDF document and prints the PDF
> content in physical printer (not in a soft printer i.e., save).  [...]
> Can I accomplish above PDF viewer feature through HTML5 canvas?

**The short answer** to your question is, no, these features cannot be implemented using a HTML5 based PDF viewer.

**Longer version:**

If the PDF is loaded in the browser the document can also be download directly by the user as well. The browser and any solution it uses to *display* the PDF will have the same access level as the user, or put differently: the user has the same access level as the browser. The link is all that is required and can be easily obtained through the dev console (or a proxy).

Files cannot be loaded directly from a user's system. Due to security reasons, the user must *pick* the file so also here he already have access to the file in order to be able to pick it.

So downloading cannot be prevented.

Depending on the implementation of the viewer printing can be prevented if the viewer comply to this status flags of the document. There is no way to distinguish what type of printer is being used from inside the browser environment. JavaScript can only invoke a print dialog without knowing anything about the printer or the print process.

Even if it could: using a pure HTML5 solution means there will be JavaScript involved, in open source at the client. Part of the source code can be overridden by an user with programming skills. In any case, an user can simply screen-grab the page and save the grab.

So no, printing cannot be forced to a physical unit (or prevented).

## HTML5 viewer

For the browser, look at [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). This is the solution Firefox is using and I believe Chrome will use in the future.

Comment: then I should go with JNLP based solution to maintain this features instead of Java Applet. But this solution makes the end-user to install the Java Runtime

Comment: But its the same like the applet - the user needs to have java installed

Comment: There are several commercial HTML5 viewers from companies like Accusoft or Box which give you control over what the user can do.